# Scattermapbox in pyqt- data selection using lasso/box select

Tags: pyqt5, plotly, mapbox

I want to select the data points using box/lasso selct from a scatter mapbox as below. My code is highlightng selected points. But they are not updated to selectedpoints attribute of fig.data[0]. When i want to print selcted points or pass them to a function, selected points are still none as initially declared.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QDialog
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QDialog


class DashboardScreen(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DashboardScreen, self).__init__()       
        
        data = {'Fid': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                'Project': [1,2,3],
                'Date': [23, 24, 25],
                'Latitude': [10, 20, 30],
                'Longitude': [70, 75, 80]}
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        
        
        fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
            lat=df['Latitude'],
            lon=df['Longitude'],
            hovertext=df['Project'],
            mode='markers',    
            marker={'size': 10, 'color': 'blue'},
            selected=dict(marker={'color': 'red'}),
            selectedpoints=[]
        ))
        
        fig.update_layout(
            mapbox_style="white-bg"  
        )
            
        fig.update_layout(mapbox_layers=[
                {
                    "below": 'traces',
                    "sourcetype": "raster",
                    "sourceattribution": "United States Geological Survey",
                    "source":  [
                "https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"
                              # "http://localhost:7000/offline_tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                               ]
                }
              ],
            margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0}
        )
        
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())

        # Create the web view
        self.webView = QWebEngineView()
        self.webView.setHtml(fig.to_html(include_plotlyjs='cdn'))
        self.layout().addWidget(self.webView)

        # Create the push button
        self.button = QPushButton("Pass Selected Data")
        self.button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.passSelectedData(fig))
        self.layout().addWidget(self.button)

        

    def passSelectedData(self, fig):       
        print(fig.data[0])
        print(fig.data[0].selectedpoints)
            
        if fig.data[0].selectedpoints:
            selected_indices = fig.data[0].selectedpoints
            selected_data = {
                'lat': [fig.data[0].lat[i] for i in selected_indices],
                'lon': [fig.data[0].lon[i] for i in selected_indices]
            }
            print(selected_data)



app = QApplication(sys.argv)
welcome = DashboardScreen()
welcome.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    except:
        logging.info("Exiting!!")
        print("Exiting!!")
```

I want solution to get the selected datapoints as array/list/dataframe